regex code improvement - support hyphen sign
i have regex:
(?:\([A-Z]+\))?FS[A-Z ]*-\d(?:[^\n,()-]*\/\d\d)?

https://regex101.com/r/udRNA5/1
i want to recognize this numbers as FS-xxxx/24/yy/xx
please help me, or give me information where i can search.
I tried change [A-Z ] position but without effect.
when I insert a hyphen character permanently, it stops detecting other


Your "current" regex would match a much larger variety of strings than you have shown in your sample. Maybe provide a larger/more reflective sample so we can try to adopt the regex - else it is hard to understand how you came up with the current version. Your current specification would yield a regex such as: FS-?\d+\/24\/[A-Z]{2}\/\d{2}, but this would match twice in your second example string. (Should it?)

thanks, can i change result to FS-771/24/HN/10 from FS771/24/HN/10

You might need to add further constraint to your regex. For example,
FS-?\d+\/24\/[A-Z]{2}\/[0-9]{2}(?=>|$)

could be an improvement, if lookaround is supported.
See here

Another example could be:
FS-?\d{3,4}\/24\/(?:HN|GF)\/[0-9]{2}(?=>|$)

See here
We assume you don't want to match FS2963/24/GF/10 in this case:

UZNANIE/VAT/72/INV/FS2963/24/GF/10/TXT/FS2963/24/GF/10>

But if you do, you can simply remove the lookahead statement at the end:
FS-?\d+\/24\/[A-Z]{2}\/\d{2}

See here

If you want to add a hyphen to those without hyphens:
(?<=FS)(?=\d+\/24\/[A-Z]{2}\/\d{2})

substituted with - may work.
Add a hyphen
Details:
The pattern (?<=FS)(?=\d+\/24\/[A-Z]{2}\/\d{2}) uses a positive lookbehind ((?<=FS)) and a positive lookahead ((?=\d+\/24\/[A-Z]{2}\/\d{2})), ensuring it matches the specified sequence without consuming any characters. You can replace it with a - to achieve your goal.

can i change for example result FS771/24/HN/10  to FS-771/24/HN/10, with - hyphen sign?

@arczitje1000 Yes, you can. Replace (?<=FS)(?=\d+\/24\/[A-Z]{2}\/\d{2}) with -?

its posiible in one code? or i have to use regex and replacement

please consider adding an explanaition as to HOW and WHY your regex works to help people who visit this question in the future

In your regexp, the hyphen is required. If you want to match string without the hyphen, you could simply make it optional using a question mark.
                        
(?:\([A-Z]+\))?FS[A-Z ]*-?\d(?:[^\n,()-]*\/\d\d)?

Now it should work correctly.
https://regex101.com/r/udRNA5/2
